# Query using LEVENSHTEIN function returning more results than expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, functions

My aim is to select similar strings in the `DETAILS` column for different items within the same date and a time difference of less than 10 minutes. The table is similar to the one shown below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| ID*  | ITEM |    DATE    |   TIME   |    DETAILS    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | XYZ  | 20.10.2019 | 12:35:10 | Some_string   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2    | ABC  | 20.10.2019 | 12:36:10 | Some_strin    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 3    | KLM  | 20.10.2019 | 12:36:10 | SSome_sng     |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 4    | XYZ  | 20.10.2019 | 12:55:10 | Another_string|
-------------------------------------------------------
```

There are three distinct values in the `ITEM` column and I want to get similar details entered for each item within the same day and a time difference of less than 10 minutes.

So, to achieve the expected result set I have used a [Levenshtein distance function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/) which returns 0 for 100% matching strings and an integer bigger than zero for non-matching strings. I  used this function inside a statement to find similar `DETAILS` among the `ITEMS` restricted with given conditions and my query is:

```
SELECT t1.ITEM, t1.DATE, t1.TIME, t1.DETAILS,
    t2.ITEM, t2.DATE, t2.TIME, t2.DETAILS
FROM MY_TABLE t1
    INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t2
    ON t1.ITEM != t2.ITEM
WHERE
    dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(t1.DETAILS, t2.DETAILS) < 20
    AND
    t1.DATE = t2.DATE
    AND
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) <= 10
```

But this statement gives me a huge table which looks like a cartesian product. How can I get the desired result?

---

### DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE](
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ITEM] nchar(10) NULL,
    [DATE] date NULL,
    [TIME] time(7) NULL,
    [DETAILS] nchar(100) NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE([ITEM],[DATE],[TIME],[DETAILS])
VALUES('XYZ', '10.20.2019', '12:35:10', 'Some_string' ),
      ('ABC', '10.20.2019', '12:36:10', 'Some_strin' ),
      ('KLM', '10.20.2019', '12:36:10', 'SSome_sng' ),
      ('XYZ', '10.20.2019', '12:55:10', 'Another_string' );
GO
```

```
CREATE function LEVENSHTEIN ( @SourceString nvarchar(100), @TargetString nvarchar(100) )
--Returns the Levenshtein Distance between @SourceString string and @TargetString
--Translated to TSQL by Joseph Gama
--Updated slightly by Phil Factor
returns int
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @Matrix Nvarchar(4000), @LD int, @TargetStringLength int, @SourceStringLength int,
@ii int, @jj int, @CurrentSourceChar nchar(1), @CurrentTargetChar nchar(1),@Cost int, 
@Above int,@AboveAndToLeft int,@ToTheLeft int, @MinimumValueOfCells int
-- Step 1: Set n to be the length of s. Set m to be the length of t. 
--                    If n = 0, return m and exit.
--    If m = 0, return n and exit.
--    Construct a matrix containing 0..m rows and 0..n columns.
if @SourceString is null or @TargetString is null return null
Select @SourceStringLength=LEN(@SourceString), 
     @TargetStringLength=LEN(@TargetString),
     @Matrix=replicate(nchar(0),(@SourceStringLength+1)*(@TargetStringLength+1))
If @SourceStringLength = 0 return @TargetStringLength
If @TargetStringLength = 0 return @SourceStringLength
if (@TargetStringLength+1)*(@SourceStringLength+1)> 4000 return -1
--Step 2: Initialize the first row to 0..n.
--     Initialize the first column to 0..m.
SET @ii=0
WHILE @ii<=@SourceStringLength
    BEGIN
    SET @Matrix=STUFF(@Matrix,@ii+1,1,nchar(@ii))--d(i, 0) = i
    SET @ii=@ii+1
    END
SET @ii=0
WHILE @ii<=@TargetStringLength
    BEGIN
    SET @Matrix=STUFF(@Matrix,@ii*(@SourceStringLength+1)+1,1,nchar(@ii))--d(0, j) = j
    SET @ii=@ii+1
    END
--Step 3 Examine each character of s (i from 1 to n).
SET @ii=1
WHILE @ii<=@SourceStringLength
    BEGIN
 
--Step 4   Examine each character of t (j from 1 to m).
    SET @jj=1
    WHILE @jj<=@TargetStringLength
        BEGIN
--Step 5 and 6
        Select 
        --Set cell d[i,j] of the matrix equal to the minimum of:
        --a. The cell immediately above plus 1: d[i-1,j] + 1.
        --b. The cell immediately to the left plus 1: d[i,j-1] + 1.
        --c. The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost: d[i-1,j-1] + cost
        @Above=unicode(substring(@Matrix,@jj*(@SourceStringLength+1)+@ii-1+1,1))+1,
        @ToTheLeft=unicode(substring(@Matrix,(@jj-1)*(@SourceStringLength+1)+@ii+1,1))+1,
        @AboveAndToLeft=unicode(substring(@Matrix,(@jj-1)*(@SourceStringLength+1)+@ii-1+1,1))
         + case when (substring(@SourceString,@ii,1)) = (substring(@TargetString,@jj,1)) 
            then 0 else 1 end--the cost
        -- If s[i] equals t[j], the cost is 0.
      -- If s[i] doesn't equal t[j], the cost is 1.
        -- now calculate the minimum value of the three
        if (@Above < @ToTheLeft) AND (@Above < @AboveAndToLeft) 
            select @MinimumValueOfCells=@Above
      else if (@ToTheLeft < @Above) AND (@ToTheLeft < @AboveAndToLeft)
            select @MinimumValueOfCells=@ToTheLeft
        else
            select @MinimumValueOfCells=@AboveAndToLeft
        Select @Matrix=STUFF(@Matrix,
                   @jj*(@SourceStringLength+1)+@ii+1,1,
                   nchar(@MinimumValueOfCells)),
           @jj=@jj+1
        END
    SET @ii=@ii+1
    END    
--Step 7 After iteration steps (3, 4, 5, 6) are complete, distance is found in cell d[n,m]
return unicode(substring(
   @Matrix,@SourceStringLength*(@TargetStringLength+1)+@TargetStringLength+1,1
   ))
END
go
```

Comment: " levenshtein distance function condition isn't applied to the result"? Are you sure? Do you have examples of strings in the result where the function returns more than 20? Is `nvarchar(100)` sufficient for the lengths of your strings?

Comment: Sorry about that part I checked it again and result table satisfies the condition.

Comment: So is there still a question here?

Comment: *"looks like a cartesian product"* - have you verified that? How many rows are input and output? Maybe the data you have is similar enough that `LEVENSHTEIN(a,b) < 20` is going be a close to the product as makes not odds (obviously less the cases where `t1.ITEM != t2.ITEM` as you have excluded them)? If you eyeball the data do you see any examples that you are sure should not be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this statement gives me a huge table which looks like a cartesian
>   product

I'd say it's because of your join.

```
FROM MY_TABLE t1
INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t2
ON t1.ITEM != t2.ITEM
```

When you use the `!=` operator you're joining each row with all other rows except ones with the same value to the column ITEM, but it doesn't avoid inverting the order of the rows and you end up with a negative difference on the TIME comparison. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE](
    [ITEM] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [DATE] [date] NULL,
    [TIME] [time](7) NULL,
    [DETAILS] [nchar](100) NULL);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE([ITEM],[DATE],[TIME],[DETAILS])
VALUES('XYZ', '10.20.2019', '12:35:10', 'ronaldo' ),
    ('XRZ', '10.20.2019', '12:36:10', 'ronalde' ),
    ('XRZ', '10.20.2019', '12:36:10', 'ronnaudus' ),
    ('PRZ', '10.20.2019', '12:55:10', 'ronal' );
```

With that sample data run this query:

```
SELECT t1.ITEM, t1.DATE, t1.TIME, t1.DETAILS,
    t2.ITEM, t2.DATE, t2.TIME, t2.DETAILS, 
    dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(t1.DETAILS, t2.DETAILS) AS 'LEVENSHTEIN',
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) AS 'DATEDIFF'
FROM MY_TABLE t1
    INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t2
    ON t1.ITEM != t2.ITEM
WHERE
    dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(t1.DETAILS, t2.DETAILS) < 20
    AND
    t1.DATE = t2.DATE
    AND
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) <= 10;
```

I've added the last two columns for it's easier to see the problem. Here's the result:

[image: Query Result]

See the negative DATEDIFF? that's the reason you're getting more lines than expected in the result. To correct that just add one more condition to your join like this:

```
SELECT t1.ITEM, t1.DATE, t1.TIME, t1.DETAILS,
    t2.ITEM, t2.DATE, t2.TIME, t2.DETAILS, 
    dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(t1.DETAILS, t2.DETAILS) AS 'LEVENSHTEIN',
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) AS 'DATEDIFF'
FROM MY_TABLE t1
    INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t2
    ON t1.ITEM != t2.ITEM
    AND (t1.DATE <= t2.DATE AND t1.TIME <= t2.TIME) --Avoid joining retroactive time
WHERE
    dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(t1.DETAILS, t2.DETAILS) < 20
    AND
    t1.DATE = t2.DATE
    AND
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) <= 10;
```

Comment: @VOLKANBAKIR, one detail about the predicate `t1.DATE = t2.DATE` you used in the `where` clause is that it might prevent results in which the time difference is less than 10min as you wish, but not from the same day. e.g. **20.10.2019 23:58:00** and  **21.10.2019 00:02:00** wouldn't be a valid result. I kept that as it was for the sake of answering your question, but you might wanna consider it.